# Managing Users and Creating Groups

Tags: users, user-roles, permissions, user-access

We're going to be transitioning from a small, outdated CMS that's no longer supported, to WordPress for our new CMS. Our old CMS allows us to restrict access on the back-end so that  by default User A couldn't edit content created by User B. Our old CMS also allows us to create teams/groups, so that if a group of content creators wanted to work together, they could share access to content while preventing others from accessing it. Basically we have a team of 50-100 people that would be using WordPress and don't want them stepping on each other's toes.

Is there a way to do this in WordPress? We're planning on running one instance of WordPress (not multisite) and posting mostly pages (not posts). The built-in roles don't seem to be able to handle restricting access, nor creating groups. I've searched and found the plugins User Role Editor and User Access Manager, but was wondering if we were going about this correctly, or if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: You can do that with WordPress, but your question, while can be interesting, it is really board for the format of this site. The answer can be really long and there can be a lot of good answers. could you try to break down the question into specific problems?

Comment: @cybmeta - Apologies, I'm used to hanging out on SO and not more than a WP novice. I don't have anything more specific to ask I suppose other than am I looking at this correctly in what WP can and can't do, and do I need a plugin to handle it? Thanks.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are, in general, off-topic here. Sorry. Read the help center about [what topics you can ask and how to ask](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: For others with the same question, I ended up using Co-Authors Plus (https://github.com/Automattic/Co-Authors-Plus). It's easy to use and just what I needed. It is (or was) also developed in part by Automattic. How  something like this isn't integrated into the core I'll never know.

Answer (score 2):

This is right. You can use Wordpress in exactly the same way as you were using your OLD CMS. Wordpress is being used by Top newspapers / magazines and websites and they've editors / authors and bloggers and ofcourse they have groups & roles. CNN, Mashabale, TechCrunch, etc are all based on Wordpress.

There are Free and Premium both type of plugins to take control of Users / Roles / Groups. You can see these other plugins as well.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-groups-restrictions/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/

http://wp-types.com/home/types-access/

There are many more that you can find with Google search.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't seen the Access plugin before, and it looks potentially very promising. Wish they had a trial or free version so I could test it.